# How to avoid duplicate subscription in Rx Subject

Tags: c#, rxjs, system.reactive, reactive

I have below method in which simply various client subscribe to this subject. I just want to handle the situation that someone accidentally doesn't subscribe multiple time. 
So, before subscribing I need to check if subject is already having subscription for same client, then don't do anything . I checked with linq method called Distinct but it return only one observer. I think there has to be direct method to do this? If anyone knows please share the same

```
class SettingManger
{
   private Subject<string> suject = new Subject<string>();

           public IDisopable SubscribeToChange(IObserver<string>subscriber)
          {
             return subject.subscribe(subscriber);
          }
}
```

Comment: where do you keep subscribers list? it is unclear from your description. On what list were you trying to run Distinct at?

Comment: @HananHazani IT IS SUBJECT FROM system.reactive assembly

Comment: For debugging, just add a `bool isSubscribed` in the class and set it to true on subscription. Check it the next time subscribe is called. For production, don't do this.

Comment: If a observer tries to subscribe more than once, what `IDisposable` will you send back?